# Tone of 和 in 暖和

Tags: tones

For words like 衣服 and 朋友, we can pronounce either with full tones as yi¹fu² and peng²you³, or with neutralized tones of the second syllable like yi¹fu⁰ and peng²you⁰.

Then comes 暖和 which confuses me. In the Taiwanese dictionaries that otherwise show full tones, this word is still spelled as nuan³huo⁰. What would be the tone of 和 if it was not neutralized? Or is this maybe a wrong question; does this syllable 和 huo⁰ only exist in neutral tone?

Comment: These may be related: [words where it is important to distinguish between the neutral tone and the citation tone](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14826/words-where-it-is-important-to-distinguish-between-the-neutral-tone-and-the-cita) and [What difference(s) does it make to use the citation tone instead of the neutral tone, for the tail character in these words?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16695/what-differences-does-it-make-to-use-the-citation-tone-instead-of-the-neutral)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

和 read huo has four pronunciations:

- huō
- huó
- huò
- huo

*Liang’an* defines neutral huo as:

> 形容某種使人感到舒適的狀態。

and gives the following example words:

> 暖和
>
> 熱和
>
> 軟和。

The definitions of the other pronunciations of huo certainly don’t fit. Why? Well because:

- huō can only be found in the word 傻傻和和 which means stupid.
- huó basically only means: to mix with water.
- huò means to mix or to blend.

But this answer isn’t very satisfying.

Knowing that the 和 in 暖和 is the same as the one in 软和 then we can look back at an entry in *ABC*:

> 软和话儿

The given Pinyin for this word is:

> ruǎnhuóhuàr

Here 和 is marked huó. It fits the idea that sometimes these 和 words are also pronounced he and hé. For instance *MOE* has the entry:

> 暖和和

written as:

> nuǎn hé hé

Again: it’s second tone. So if you want an answer with a tone & not just with a neutral tone, the second tone is your best bet.

Comment: I just stumbled upon another *ABC* entry that further supports this: the duplicated  暖暖和和 nuǎnnuǎnhuóhuó.

Comment: @svenper Is that really in ABC? I don’t see it in my Pleco copy.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the erhua: 暖暖和和儿〔----兒〕nuǎnnuǎnhuóhuór