# Reading of 匙 meaning “key” (as in 钥匙)

Tags: pronunciation, tones

Essentially the same as [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35831/tone-of-%E5%92%8C-in-%E6%9A%96%E5%92%8C), but the solutions there don't seem applicable here. Both isolated and in compounds, I can only find 匙 as either shi⁰ or chi² “spoon”.

Can this character in this context have a specific tone, and if so in what resource can it be found? Or is looking at tone alone misleading; is/was it possible to read 钥匙 as yao⁴chi²? (Where?)

Comment: spoon: chi2, usually 儿化, chier; key: shi, neutral tone, though the dictionary form is shi4.

Answer (score 3):

> 匙 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/371/
>
> [粵] ci4 | [國] chi2 : spoon
>
> [粵] si4 | [國] shi5 : key

When '匙' means 'spoon', it is read as /chi2/ in Mandarin

When '匙' means 'key', it is read as /shi5/ in Mandarin

It doesn't matter it is by itself or in a compound word

There are other examples of single character that have more than one meaning and pronounced differently for each meaning.  樂 is one of them. When 樂 means 'joy' it is read as /le4/; When 樂 means 'music' it is read as /yue4/

Comment: Did you mean it is read as shi5 when it means key?

Answer (score 2):

My digital copy of《汉语大词典》gives a first tone:

> 匙
>   shī
>   钥匙

I'd like to check this against a paper copy though, just to be sure.

---

Grand Ricci gives:

> shí (or chí)
>   1. Cuiller
>   2. N. f.

This seems to be the more likely of the two as it tonally fits the chí pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

In Mandarin Chinese, 钥匙 is yao4shi0. The 匙 here can only have the neutral tone.

《现代汉语词典》 has an entry for 匙(shi0), with a very brief explanation: 见1466页【钥匙】（see 钥匙 on page 1466）. The word 钥匙 only has one pronunciation listed: yao5shi0. (I don't have digital version of this dictionary.)

Also you can see [匙](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%8C%99) and [钥匙](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%92%A5%E5%8C%99) on zdic.net, which also only lists only "shi5" for the 匙 in 钥匙.

匙 seems to be "shi5" only in 钥匙，and 钥匙 is always yao4shi5.