# 很有 pronounced rather like hěnyòu instead of hěnyǒu

Tags: pronunciation, tones, sandhi

In an intermediate level class (B1 or B2 level perhaps / around HSK 5 or 6), several example sentences were used to illustrate some vocabulary. The teacher, a native speaker with fairly standard pronunciation as far as I can tell, was not concentrating on pronunciation or tones. I do not remember them exactly, but they all had a structure similar to:

这个人**很有**X

X could be 品味, or 才能, or 办法 or some other words.

In any case I was struck by hearing  很有 read in these sentences as if the 有 was like a fourth tone. Also I am pretty sure that 很 was quite low; nothing like the second tone that would be expected by consecutive third tones. Which surprised me a bit.

Using [tone letter notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_letter#Numerical_values), 很有 sounded like this:

- hen (꜐ or ꜑ / 2 or 1 ); short; rather like a neutral tone (轻声).
- you (꜏꜑ / 31 or ꜎꜑ / 41); stressed perceptibly more than 很

I do not think I have seen anything describing this intonation/pronunciation. I would like to know if it has been described anywhere / if it is a commonly observed phenomenon. For 很, perhaps it could be a case of "Quasi-neutral tones in speech to contrast intonation." as mentioned in [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/43256/2508)? But for 有 sounding like a fourth tone, I never saw that described anywhere.

So my question is: what is going on with the intonation/tones for 很有 in this sort of sentence?

Comment: There are several pitches for neutral tone, depending on the tone before. Neutral tone can be rather high-sounding (e.g. 椅子 曲子 嫂子).
很有 is generally pronounced with rising tone (tone 2) and a low tone (tone 3) because of [tone sandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_sandhi).

Answer (score 2):

1. The obligate tone sandhi for consecutive third-tones are rendered as follows:

   | Phrase | Before | After |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `很有品味` | `3334` | `2234` |
   | `很有才能` | `3322` | `2322` |
   | `很有辦法` | `3343` | `2343` |

   In particular, the `333 -> 223` change in `很有品味` is explained [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/43255/27428).
2. Possible facultative tone sandhi in `很有` in quick speech include:

   - For all `很有XX` examples: blurring of tones (*quasi*-neutral, as explained [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/43256/27428); to avoid confusion, let us not use the dotted tone letters normally reserved for real neutral tones, and let the one-lettered pitches reflect their brevity) in the presence of stress on `XX` out of contextual need (as explained [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/43564/27428)).
   - For `很有品味`: a blurry rising trend for consecutive *de facto* second-tones, as explained in the `葡萄牙` example [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/43290/27428) (perhaps something like `˦ ˥`).
   - For `很有才能` and `很有辦法`: a blurry dropping trend (perhaps something like `˧ ˩`).
3. What you seem to be implying is that the teacher pronounced `很有`, in quick speech, with a go-up-and-down pitch change, i.e. `˨ ˧˩`. Now, is this possible? If you are absolutely sure there is no mishearing or mislabelling on your part, then I think the teacher did not conform to standardised Putonghua well (i.e., this is a mispronunciation on their part). However, I am not entirely sure about your labelling `有` with two tone letters – is it worth that many, especially when it is expected to be blurred over? After all, we are treading on very thin ice here – it is very hard to capture every nuance of *facultative* tone sandhi. Unless I hear the teacher's audio, or an audio from an online source (e.g. YouTube) that you believe is close enough to the teacher's, I cannot provide a definite answer.

---

**Edit**

Now that we have made clear this was normal-paced, I am starting to suspect this is similar to the case of `比較`, where some people say it as `(bǐ jiǎo ->) bí jiǎo` instead of the conventional `bǐ jiào` (see [here](https://www.chinese-forums.com/forums/topic/20926-non-dictionary-pronunciations/) for more examples). The link contains examples of non-dictionary readings.

I also found evidence where `有` may be pronounced as `yòu`: see [here](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E6%9C%89). Its use is relatively limited, i.e., when acting as a loan word (通假) for `又` in classical Chinese*, or when denoting numerical remainders (e.g. `七十有七人`), both of which are not the applicable to `很有`. However, 教育部重編國語辭典修訂本 claims `yòu` and `yǒu` are interchangeable (I for one think this is rarely practised in real life). At any rate, the teacher's choice of pronunciation is not mainstream. I also believe this is caused more by the polyphony of `有` than facultative tone sandhi during quick speech.

* Also supported by 余培英（2012）《多音字學習手冊》。北京：商務。
[image: scan]

Comment: It was normal-paced or perhaps slightly leisurely speech; neither especially fast nor especially slow. I think I heard ˨ ˧˩ (2 31) or ˨ ˦˩ (2 41), in several example sentences. The stress was on the second part, the 有; the first part, the 很, was short and unstressed. // I do not have any audio for this - it may just be one of life's mysteries... Thank you for your help.

Comment: Another possible explanation is dialectal influence - do you know the background of the teacher? I really cannot think of any justification why it should be pronounced like so in standard Putonghua. If that be the case, I am not too familiar with dialects, unfortunately.

Comment: I do not know the teacher's background. // I was not aware of the distinction between dotted tone letters (꜍꜎꜏꜐꜑) and the "linked" ones (˥ ˦ ˧ ˨ ˩). I was using the dotted tone letters as replacements for the undotted ones as I find the way the adjacent linked tone letters combine together on my PC confusing. It appears this was a mistake. I think I should perhaps edit my question to use linked tone letters; I can learn to read the adjacent "linked" tone letters.

Comment: I edited my answer which contains the suggestion that maybe this has nothing to do with tonal changes.

Comment: Could it be just a bit of overemphasis by the speaker on the slight drop that is inherent to the third tone? That is, as far as I can recall, the semi-third tone is not truly flat, but does drop slightly (21?). The speaker could have been just emphasizing the 有 in the example sentences or doing something that emphasizes/separates out the word right after 有 (equivalent to a slight pause in English). Could something like this make the semi-third tone come out with a stronger drop than normal?

Comment: @2ndQuantized that seems plausible to me.

Comment: @2ndQuantized that wouldn’t explain the case for 很有品味.

Comment: @LParker If there was a sufficient pause between 很有 and 品味 or sufficient emphasis on 很有, would native speakers tend to not transition such a third tone to a second tone because it naturally feels more like a break rather than being continuous (even though it is more so something in between)? I don't know the answer and it may be speaker- and situation-dependent, but I know that emphasis or listing examples can cause interesting sound changes in English and I am wondering if this is the underlying reason.

Comment: @2ndQuantized For 很有品味, both 2234 and 2334 are possible.